# Why is pip installing an incompatible package version?

Tags: python, pip

I am using pip 20.0.2 on Ubuntu, and installing a bunch of requirements from a requirements file. For some reason, pip is deciding to install `idna==2.9`[(link)](https://pypi.org/project/idna), even though that is not a compatible version with one of my directly listed dependencies. So I used `python -m pipdeptree -r` within the virtualenv that I'm installing everything to, and I see this listed for `idna`:

```
idna==2.9                                         
  - cryptography==2.3.1 [requires: idna>=2.1]
  - requests==2.22.0 [requires: idna>=2.5,<2.9]
    - requests-oauthlib==1.3.0 [requires: requests>=2.0.0]
      - social-auth-core==3.2.0 [requires: requests-oauthlib>=0.6.1]
        - social-auth-app-django==2.1.0 [requires: social-auth-core>=1.2.0]
    - responses==0.10.9 [requires: requests>=2.0]
    - social-auth-core==3.2.0 [requires: requests>=2.9.1]                           
      - social-auth-app-django==2.1.0 [requires: social-auth-core>=1.2.0]
```

As we can see, my two direct dependencies (`cryptography` and `requests`), are what require `idna`. According to those, it looks like pip should decide to install `2.8`, because it is the latest version that will fulfill the constraints.

Why is pip instead installing `idna` 2.9, as indicated by the top line of that output, and this error message when running `pip install -r requirements.txt`:

```
ERROR: requests 2.22.0 has requirement idna<2.9,>=2.5, but you'll have idna 2.9 which is incompatible.
```

EDIT: the contents of requirements.txt and it's children, as requested in the comments:

```
# requirements.txt
-r requirements/requirements-base.txt
-r requirements/requirements-testing.txt

# requirements-base.txt
cryptography~=2.3.1
pyjwt~=1.6.4
requests~=2.22.0
social-auth-app-django~=2.1.0

# requirements-testing.txt
hypothesis~=3.87.0
pytest~=3.6.2
pytest-django~=3.3.2
pytest-cov~=2.5.1
responses~=0.10.5
```

Edit 2: I've created a minimally viable example. For this example, here is requirements.txt:

```
cryptography~=2.3.1
requests~=2.22.0
```

And here are the commands I ran from start to finish in a fresh directory:

```
virtualenv -p python3.6 -v venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
```

And the full output:

```
Collecting cryptography~=2.3.1
  Downloading cryptography-2.3.1-cp34-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.1 MB 2.0 MB/s 
Collecting requests~=2.22.0
  Downloading requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 57 kB 18.5 MB/s 
Collecting asn1crypto>=0.21.0
  Downloading asn1crypto-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 103 kB 65.4 MB/s 
Collecting idna>=2.1
  Downloading idna-2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 58 kB 71.4 MB/s 
Collecting six>=1.4.1
  Downloading six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7
  Downloading cffi-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (399 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 399 kB 30.3 MB/s 
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 125 kB 46.7 MB/s 
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Downloading certifi-2019.11.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 156 kB 65.1 MB/s 
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
  Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 133 kB 60.8 MB/s 
Collecting pycparser
  Downloading pycparser-2.19.tar.gz (158 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 158 kB 25.0 MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: pycparser
  Building wheel for pycparser (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for pycparser: filename=pycparser-2.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=111031 sha256=030a1449dd5902f2f03e9e2f8f9cc6760503136a9243e965237a1ece1196502a
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-c_dx8qi5/wheels/c6/6b/83/2608afaa57ecfb0a66ac89191a8d9bad71c62ca55ee499c2d0
Successfully built pycparser
ERROR: requests 2.22.0 has requirement idna<2.9,>=2.5, but you'll have idna 2.9 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: asn1crypto, idna, six, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, urllib3, certifi, chardet, requests
Successfully installed asn1crypto-1.3.0 certifi-2019.11.28 cffi-1.14.0 chardet-3.0.4 cryptography-2.3.1 idna-2.9 pycparser-2.19 requests-2.22.0 six-1.14.0 urllib3-1.25.8
```

Comment: Ugh, I think I've spotted it, during the install: `Collecting idna~=2.8 Using cached idna-2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)`. That damn pip cache looks to have bitten me. It's so strange to me that pip will use a cached version, even though it doesn't properly fulfill the requirements.

Comment: Hm, nope. Even with `pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir`, it still collects the wrong version: `Collecting idna>=2.1
  Downloading idna-2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 58 kB 35.7 MB/s
`

Comment: To get this clear, what's the exact command that caused pip to install this version of `idna`? Was it installed as part of what's listed in `requirements.txt`? Then what exactly is listed in that file? Or did you install it separately from `requirements.txt`?

Comment: All I am ever using to install requirements is `pip install -r requirements.txt`, the contents of which I'll post above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pip does not have a dependency resolver. If you tell it to install package `foo` without any qualifications, you’re getting the newest version of `foo`, even if it conflicts with other packages you’ve already installed.

Other solutions like [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) exist which *do* have the logic to keep everything compatible. If you need this, consider using something like that instead of plain pip.

Comment: I don't understand this answer - pip certainly does install the dependencies of the packages you tell it to install. For instance, in this very example I am telling it to install `cryptography~=2.3.1` and `requests~=2.22.0`, and pip is fetching those, as well as their dependencies which includes `idna`. Both cryptography and requests specify specific version of `idna` which they support - they aren't simply calling for `idna`, but for specific versions thereof (as shown in the pipdeptree output).

Comment: Right, but let’s say pip installs `cryptography` first. It picks the newest versions of `idna` that `cryptography` can use. It doesn’t consider `requests` at all! Then when it tries to install `requests`, it sees that `idna` is already installed and doesn’t do anything more about it. That’s what poetry does differently: it considers that both `cryptography` and `requests` both require `idna`, and finds the best version that satisfies both of their requirements. If there’s no overlap (like one needs `idna<2` and the other needs `idna>=2`) it will tell you so that you can fix it.

Comment: And what do you know, if I flip the order of dependencies in the minimal example, it installs correctly. Wow, I never knew this, I always assumed pip was doing some sort of dependency resolver. TIL. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Yeah, that’s why tools like poetry have become so popular: doing this stuff manually when you have a whole lot of packages can be a pain in the neck.

Comment: @fildred13 There is an ongoing work on implementing a dependency resolver for pip. Here is the related issue on Github: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988

Comment: I can confirm that `pip 21.0.1` does have dependency resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 20.3, pip has a backtracking dependency resolver.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/dependency-resolution/

Current version as of 2023-05-08 is `pip-23.1.2`.

Updgrade:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```