# Why does pip install sometimes pick a incompatible version?

Tags: python, pip

In my python package htrest (https://pypi.org/project/htrest/) I have the following requirements:

```
requirements = [
    'htheatpump==1.2.1',
    'Flask==1.1.1',
    'flask-restx==0.1.1',
    'Flask-BasicAuth==0.2.0',
    # put package requirements here
]
```

When I install it using `pip install htrest` it will fail sometimes with the following message:

```
flask-restx 0.1.1 has requirement werkzeug<=0.16.1, but you'll have werkzeug 1.0.0 which is incompatible.
```

It looks like that pip is choosing `werkzeug==1.0.0` because of the requirements of `Flask` (`Werkzeug>=0.15`)

```
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.15 (from Flask==1.1.1->htrest)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/a5/d6f8a6e71f15364d35678a4ec8a0186f980b3bd2545f40ad51dd26a87fb1/Werkzeug-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

although `flask-restx` requires `werkzeug<=0.16.1`.

On the other hand, sometimes pip will choose the suitable version of `werkzeug` (`0.16.1`):

```
Collecting werkzeug<=0.16.1 (from flask-restx==0.1.1->htrest)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/e4/a859d2fe516f466642fa5c6054fd9646271f9da26b0cac0d2f37fc858c8f/Werkzeug-0.16.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

to fit the requirements of `Flask` **and** `flask-restx`.

Can anyone explain me the reason and how to fix this?

Regards,
Daniel.

Comment: Explicitly set the `wekzeug` requirement with a version?

Comment: The bug https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988 was filed in 2013. Still open.

Comment: [`pip` does not have a dependency resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60303682/7976758). See [Dependency Hell project](https://dephell.org/).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+dependency+resolver

Answer (score 1):

By default the `pip install <package_name>` command always looks for the latest version of the package and installs it. At the same time, It also searches for **latest versions of dependencies** listed in the package metadata and installs those dependencies to insure that the package has all the requirements it needs.

If you want to install a previous version you must specify this version. [This article provides full details on how pip works](https://realpython.com/what-is-pip/)

In your case, you should proceed like this:

```
pip3 uninstall Werkzeug        # uninstalling the current Werkzeug
pip3 install Werkzeug==0.16.1  # install specific version of Werkzeug
```

Comment: Ok, but flask-restx requires werkzeug<=0.16.1 and Flask requires werkzeug>=0.15. Why does pip not choose 0.16.1 allways during the pip install? This would satisfy booth requirements!

Comment: Because `pip` doesn't have recursive dependency resolver.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem for flask as long as werkzeug is greater than or equal to 0.15. In this case werkzeug version's is 16.01.

Comment: @phd thanks, that was the answer I was searching for. And it looks like the order of the package installation (Flask and flask-restx) and therefore the needed werkzeug version is not the same for each pip install call?!