# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument tryign to clone to github pages

Tags: python, github-pages, mkdocs

Trying to upload files to github for the first time! everything seems setup ok when deploying to a website with MKDocs but not to github.

I'm doing it by MKdocs gh-deploy

with little success at all, I have never done this before so please take it easy on me!
I'm getting the above error and I have tried to make a docs folder on GitHub but still getting this error can anyone help me on this as I can carry on just uploading to a website but then no use in GitHub for others!

I'm using python 3.94 with pip all updated

error OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument [image]

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.mkdocs.org/) says *"MkDocs supports Python versions 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, and pypy3."*, but you're using Python 3.9. How did you manage to install it?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60303682/why-is-pip-installing-an-incompatible-package-version

Comment: no issues installing it and works great to a website done in two secs! Just Github the issue! :-) take a look at the site! https://cyb-netics.com/

Comment: is it best I uninstall it and go to version 3.8? if so what's the best process to do it safely without losing all my files and setups?

Comment: changed Python to version 3.8 and still have the same error message!

Comment: That's good to know. Perhaps contact the developers to report a bug. I don't know anything about `MkDocs` other than what I found with google and posted here.